# dual monitor, ubuntu 14.04, second monitor isn't detected, using VGA-HDMI adapter

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors

I tried to connect an old monitor Acer P193W to my acer apire z3-605 using VGA-HDMI adapter. After connecting the monitor I went to settings > displays and there was just built-in monitor. Tried changing to proprietary drivers through software & updates from fglrx. nothing

```
lshw -short
/0/100/1/0             display        Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
/0/100/2               display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
```

from `xorg.conf`

```
Section "ServerLayout" 
Identifier "amd-layout"
    Screen 0 "amd-screen" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "amd-device"
    Driver "fglrx"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "amd-monitor"
    Option "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amd-screen"
    Device "amd-device"
    Monitor "amd-monitor"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

from `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 580mm x 360mm
   1920x1080      59.7*+
   1680x1050      69.9     60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      74.8     70.0     60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0     75.0     70.0     60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

from `lspci`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
```

I just don't get it. Did I buy wrong adapter? Do I have to update drivers? To be sure I re-installed ubuntu to 14.04 x64, couldn't find any other thread answering my question.

Comment: All those things say there is nothing plugged into a second monitor, which leads me to believe that this adapter is not compatible with Ubuntu.